# What is the meaning of this pData[1+2*i]<<8|pData[2+2*i] C++ syntax?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bitwise-operators

what is the meqaning of `pData[1+2*i]<<8|pData[2+2*i]` where `pData[ ]` is the array containing BYTE data?
I have the following function
in the main function

```
{
..........
....
BYTE Receivebuff[2048];
..
ReceiveWavePacket(&Receivebuff[i], nNextStep);
....
...
..
}
```

Where Receivebuff is the array of type BYTE.

```
ReceiveWavePacket(BYTE * pData, UINT nSize)
{
 CString strTest;
 for(int i = 0 ; i < 60 ; i++)
 {
  strTest.Format("%d\n",(USHORT)(pData[1+2*i]<<8|pData[2+2*i]));
  m_edStatData.SetWindowTextA(strTest);
          }
}
```

I want to know the meaning of "`,(USHORT)(pData[1+2*i]<<8|pData[2+2*i])`.

Can any body please help me?

Comment: What templatetypedef said. Also, note that if I were you, I'd use that parameter `UINT nSize` somewhere -- possiby as a loop boundary to prevent me from reading past the bounds of `pData`...

Answer (score 12):

This seems to be code for synthesizing a 16-bit value out of two eight-bit values.  If you'll note, the math has the form

```
(a << 8) | b
```

For suitable a and b.  This first part, (a << 8), takes the eight bits in a and shifts them up eight positions, giving a 16- bit value whose first eight bits are the bits from a and whose second eight bits are all zero.  Applying the bitwise OR operator between this new value and the value of b creates a new sixteen-bit value whose first eight bits are the bits of a (because zero-extending b for the OR step leaves these bits intact) and whose lower eight bits are the bits of b, since ORing zero bits with the bits of b yields b.

Comment: do you mean 2 eight *bit* values ( not eight-byte )? ( `pData[1+2*i]` is 8 bits in size - if BYTE on his implementation means 8 bits ).

Comment: Thank you templatetypedef and also BeeBand...Both of you guys are right...and you really helped me a lot...speially temptypedef for your explanation using the example of a and b and the logical OR ing....

Answer (score 0):

I think @templatetypedef is correct, it does look like code that creates a 16-bit value by logical OR'ing two 8 bit values. ( since it's OR'ing two elements from your array of BYTE's ).

Logical OR'ing of two bits basically means, if either of the bits is `1` then the result is 1 ("this bit OR that bit").

As a further example, take a look at this function that takes a pointer to a char (that is 8 bits in size), and returns an integer ( in this implementation that means 32 bits).

```
int Read32(const char *pcData)
{
    return ( (pcData[3]<<24) & 0xff | pcData[2]<<16 | pcData[1]<<8 | pcData[0]);
}
```

If `pcData` is a pointer to an array of `char` - then it takes the 3rd char it finds and it shifts it by 24 bits:

e.g.

if `pcData[3]` was 10110001 then it is now

`10110001000000000000000000000000`

It takes this 32 bit value and subsequently OR's it with pcData[2], shifted by 16 bits - which means that if `pcData[2]` is `11111111` then the 32 bit value is now:

`10110001111111110000000000000000`

and so on with `pcData[1]` and `pcData[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

@templatetypedef's answer is correct, but there is another interesting thing going on here:

```
(pData[1+2*i]<<8|pData[2+2*i])
```

`i` goes from 0 to 59, so this will process 60 words, starting with `pData[1]`  (1+2*0 
== 1).
This means that the first byte in the array is never processed, which seems odd.  Why isn't this the more natural `pData[2*i]<<8|pData[2*i+1]`?

One possibility:  Word data can be stored in a byte stream 2 ways:  the word 0xAA11 can be stored as 0xAA 0x11 or 0x11 0xAA.   Imagine it is the latter.

For the words :        `0xAA11 0xBB22 0xCC33 ...`
The byte stream will be `11 AA 22 BB 33 CC ...`

Parsing with the 'natural' method would give `0x11AA 0x22BB...`, which is obviously wrong.

This code will print    `0xAA22 0xBB33, 0xCC44 ....`,  which will probably pass a quick-look sanity check, but is actually totally incorrect.

I hope the extra +1 wasn't added to "fix" the endianness issue.